# Class inheritance in PHP - how to handle this case?

Tags: php, inheritance

I have 2 classes, one is in *\myProject\app\code\core\Zend\Mime.php* and the other in *\myProject\app\code\local\Zend\Mime.php*.

Both classes start like that:

```
class Zend_Mime {
    ...
```

How could the one located in \myProject\app\code\local\Zend\Mime.php extend the other one?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Its Magento, so I cant really change much here, I dont think there are namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly do the extension, because both classes use the same name, so there's name conflict. But you can do this to get that worked around. Make third class `My_Zend_Mime` (or any other name you like, yet make sure it is more unique) like this:

```
include 'myProject\app\code\local\Zend\Mime.php';
class My_Zend_Mime extends Zend_Mime {}
```

and then your `\myProject\app\code\core\Zend\Mime.php` class should extend `My_Zend_Mime`.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, so what goes in which class exactly?

Comment: Nothing extra. It just extends other class to give you new class name in the namespace for further use.

Comment: You said: and then make another Zend_Mime class extending My_Zend_Mime

Which class is that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use namespaces:

```
namespace myProject\app\code\local\Zend\Mime
use myProject\app\code\core\Zend\Mime  
class Zend_Mime extends Mime {
```

or with `require_once` statement:

```
require_once(/myProject/app/code/core/Zend/Mime.php);
class Zend_Mime extends Mime {
```